# Building wpa_supplicant with 'mm' command

Tags: android, android-source

I am new to Android. I have the entire source code of Android for the imx platform. I would like to build the wpa_supplicant folder present under external folder. Everytime I make a change, instead of building the entire source, I would like to build only the wpa_supplicant  folder. I have read that using the 'mm' command I can do it. However, i am not sure where to find the 'mm' command. For when I type #mm external/wpa_supplicant_8, I get the following error message displayed:

The program 'mm' can be found in the following packages:
 * mountmanager
 * multimail
Try: apt-get install

I am not sure if I need to do an apt-get install or the binary is present somewhere I else. Can someone help me with this? Also, how do I compile only a single application present in external folder? Please help.

Comment: Did you run `source build/envsetup.sh` from the root of your source tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the `build/envsetup.sh` script from your root folder:

`path/to/android# . ./build/envsetup.sh`

Then `lunch` for your device, and you'll be able to `mm` as necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Android directory and run `$:source ./build/envsetup.sh`
2. 'android$:lunch` and select the configuration which you are building.
3. Now go to the directory where project located and execute `mm` or 'mma' (to build the dependencies also)